# Most efficient way to remove unwanted vertices in an object with 59,000 points?

Tags: edit-mode, 3d-printing, point-clouds

I have imported a 3D-scanned .OBJ file from KScan3D, which is 3D scanning software. I am trying to scan a model car, but would like to remove all the unnecessary points for the purposes of 3D printing. The scan included much of the floor, which I would like to remove.

Below is a picture of the mesh:

[image]

What is the fastest way to eliminate the points on the floor? Is there a "drag-and-delete" tool added to recent versions of Blender?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In edit mode, press <kbd>C</kbd>, that will enter you into a Circle select. Just hold <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> and drag over what you want deleted. When you have selected all you want to delete, Right click. Then press <kbd>delete</kbd> (or <kbd>x</kbd>) and chose vertices.

There is also a border selection method, which works in ether edit mode or object mode. Press <kbd>B</kbd>, just drag with the <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> held down, when you release it the selection is done.  Delete the same way as above.  If you selected too much you can unselect it by, dragging with the <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> in either border select or circle select mode.

Comment: Thank you! That did it! For any true newbies reading this, circle select is used in Edit mode.

Comment: Very true, sorry if my not mentioning edit mode confused you. Answer updated.

Comment: By using the mouse wheel you can also increase/decrease the circle size (C select in edit mode). The same tool deselects the vertices/edges/faces, if you press the wheel/third button.